# Call variable from view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I am trying to call **$data['form_value']** from view in Codeigniter, but that array returns empty.

Here is my Controller:

```
$data['field'] = $this->cc->get_form_names($data['selid']);
foreach($data['field'] as $key=>$valuee) {
    $data['form_value'] = $this->cc->get_form_value($valuee->select);
}
```

Now in the View:

```
foreach($field as $key=>$valuee) {
    echo "<span\"> ".$valuee->disp_name." :</span>";
    <select name=\"\">";
    foreach($form_value as $v=>$vv) {
        $value = $vv->select;
        echo "<option value=\"".$vv->select."\" >".$vv->select."</option>";
    }
    echo"</select> ";
}
```

When I do **var_dump($form_value)** it return **array(0) { }**

How would I get that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting form_value in loop. Try below code in your controller.

```
$form_value = array();
foreach($data['field'] as $key=>$valuee) {
    $form_value[] = $this->cc->get_form_value($valuee->select);
}
$data["form_value "] = $form_value ;
```

Comment: If $data["form_value "] is not inside a foreach() in a controller it works fine, but I needed to set its param. And then I putting it inside a foreach again in the View.

Comment: Then do it in view itself Instead of doing same work in controller and view.

Comment: I was hoping it would be a better way to approach this, but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **`Controller`** code like this,

```
$data['field'] = $this->cc->get_form_names($data['selid']);

foreach($data['field'] as $key=>$valuee) {
    $data['form_value'][] = $this->cc->get_form_value($valuee->select);
}
```

**`$data['form_value']`** should be an array to loop through it. You are using it as string and trying to loop through it.

Hope this helps :)